# A Function with multiple outputs in C#

Tags: c#, function, return

I want to define a function with two outputs. The first one is a boolean variable and the second one is 2D array with unknown numbers of rows and columns but the array will be defined if the boolean variable is true and if the boolean variable is false, the array is not defined. how can I define this function? I am thankful if anybody can exemplify it in an example. 
Thanks

Comment: Can you just return a `Tuple<bool, array>`? Or make your own class and return containing both and return an instance of that.

Comment: Either return an object which is a composite of the two or use an output parameter.

Comment: Why not just return `null` instead of false ?

Comment: Also you need to have a compelling reason for using arrays instead of a better collection type.

Comment: out variable will be very much helpful for u.

just declare 2d array variable as

out int arr[]
anr return boolean variable

return true;
out variable will return u array and return true or false will return u boolean result.

For ex:

public void func1(out int arr[])
{
  //your code here
  return boolVariable;
}

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this .

```
Tuple<string, int> NameAndId()
{
    // This method returns multiple values.
    return new Tuple<string, int>("Test", 100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not return `null` if array is not defined?

```
  public static bool MyMethod(out int[,] array) {
    array = null;

    ...
  }
```

....

```
  int[,] data;

  if (MyMethod(out data)) {
    ....
  }
```

Or in case of C# 7.0+

```
  if (MyMethod(out var data)) {
    ....
  }
```

**Edit:** if you want to return an *array*, but you don't know its `Length` (or want to adjust it) you can try working with `List<T>` and put `.ToArray()` in the end:

```
  using System.Linq;
  ...

  List<int> list = new List<int>();

  list.Add(1);
  list.Add(5); 
  list.Add(10);
  ...
  list.Remove(5);
  ...
  list.RemoveAt(0);
  ...
  array = list.ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I know how I should return the array with unknown size? For each iteration of my algorithm, the size of the array will change. I am thankful if you can exemplify it.